# Why doesn't polymorphism work without pointers/references?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, virtual

I did find some questions already on StackOverflow with similar title, but when I read the answers, they were focusing on different parts of the question, which were really specific (e.g. STL/containers).

Could someone please show me, why you must use pointers/references for implementing polymorphism? I can understand pointers may help, but surely references only differentiate between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference?

Surely so long as you allocate memory on the heap, so that you can have dynamic binding, then this would have been enough. Obviously not.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c

Comment: Heap vs stack allocation is completely orthogonal to static vs dynamic binding.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In C++, an object always has a fixed type and size known at compile-time and (if it can and does have its address taken) always exists at a fixed address for the duration of its lifetime. These are features inherited from C which help make both languages suitable for low-level systems programming. (All of this is subject to the as-if, rule, though: a conforming compiler is free to do whatever it pleases with code as long as it can be proven to have no detectable effect on any behavior of a conforming program that is guaranteed by the standard.)

A `virtual` function in C++ is defined (more or less, no need for extreme language lawyering) as executing based on the run-time type of an object; when called directly on an object this will always be the compile-time type of the object, so there is no polymorphism when a `virtual` function is called this way.

Note that this didn't necessarily have to be the case: object types with `virtual` functions are usually implemented in C++ with a per-object pointer to a table of `virtual` functions which is unique to each type. If so inclined, a compiler for some hypothetical variant of C++ could implement assignment on objects (such as `Base b; b = Derived()`) as copying both the contents of the object and the `virtual` table pointer along with it, which would easily work if both `Base` and `Derived` were the same size. In the case that the two were not the same size, the compiler could even insert code that pauses the program for an arbitrary amount of time in order to rearrange memory in the program and update all possible references to that memory in a way that could be proven to have no detectable effect on the semantics of the program, terminating the program if no such rearrangement could be found: this would be very inefficient, though, and could not be guaranteed to ever halt, obviously not desirable features for an assignment operator to have.

So in lieu of the above, polymorphism in C++ is accomplished by allowing references and pointers to objects to reference and point to objects of their declared compile-time types and any subtypes thereof. When a `virtual` function is called through a reference or pointer, and the compiler cannot prove that the object referenced or pointed to is of a run-time type with a specific known implementation of that `virtual` function, the compiler inserts code which looks up the correct `virtual` function to call a run-time. It did not have to be this way, either: references and pointers could have been defined as being non-polymorphic (disallowing them to reference or point to subtypes of their declared types) and forcing the programmer to come up with alternative ways of implementing polymorphism. The latter is clearly possible since it's done all the time in C, but at that point there's not much reason to have a new language at all.

In sum, the semantics of C++ are designed in such a way to allow the high-level abstraction and encapsulation of object-oriented polymorphism while still retaining features (like low-level access and explicit management of memory) which allow it to be suitable for low-level development. You could easily design a language that had some other semantics, but it would not be C++ and would have different benefits and drawbacks.

Comment: So are we saying that the run-time system will only make vtable lookups if it sees the object was declared with a pointer, and that is just how the C++ design was? Hence polymorphism only works with a pointer (or reference) because thats the only way the run-time will make a vtable lookup and hence perform polymorphism?

Comment: It's not that the object is declared with a pointer, it's that you're calling a `virtual` function through a pointer or reference. An object is always instantiated as a complete type known at compile-time, whether it gets referenced by a pointer or reference later doesn't affect the object itself. (`new` returns a pointer to an object on the heap, but conceptually the object is still there with its compile-time type until it's destroyed)

Comment: You can have object variables on the heap (if they're instance variables of a heap-allocated object, for instance) or pointers to objects allocated on the stack, the semantics are the same regardless.

Comment: Just take a look at the first block of code in LuchianGrigore's answer, `Base * b` is a polymorphic pointer and happens to be pointing to an object of `Derived` which is on the stack.

Comment: Stephen, do you know of any books that go into this sort of thing especially well?

Comment: Would there be any practical way of defining a base type to reserve a certain amount of extra storage for derived types, such that any derived type which doesn't add too much stuff can store everything "in-place", and larger types could store commonly-used fields "in-place" along with a pointer to supplemental data?

Comment: @Elliot Yes, a book detailing these kind of questions would be valuable.

Comment: c++ is overcomplicated and non-intuitive.

Comment: Reading your third paragraph, am I to understand that, when you assign a derived class to a base class instance, it doesn't copy the derived class's vptr?  Does it know to replace it with the vptr for the base class?

Answer (score 80):

"Surely so long as you allocate memory on the heap" - where the memory is allocated has nothing to do with it. It's all about the semantics. Take, for instance:

```
Derived d;
Base* b = &d;
```

`d` is on the stack (automatic memory), but polymorphism will still work on `b`.

If you don't have a base class pointer or reference to a derived class, polymorphism doesn't work because you no longer have a derived class. Take

```
Base c = Derived();
```

The `c` object isn't a `Derived`, but a `Base`, because of **slicing**. So, technically, polymorphism still works, it's just that you no longer have a `Derived` object to talk about.

Now take

```
Base* c = new Derived();
```

`c` just points to some place in memory, and you don't really care whether that's actually a `Base` or a `Derived`, but the call to a `virtual` method will be resolved dynamically.

Comment: I thought slicing was to do with liskovs substitution principle, not pointers? So Derived d = new Base() would cause slicing because a Base is not a Derived.... but a Derived is a Base. So what is it which the pointer does which makes it a derived class (you said "polymorphism doesnt work because you no longer have a derived class"- why?)

Comment: @user997112 when you construct `Base c = Derived()` (which may or may not work, depending on what functions you have implemented), c is still a `Base` and has only the memory layout and instance variables of a `Base` object. (For one thing, `Derived` might be larger than `Base`.) Every variable in C++ has a specific amount of storage allocated to it at compile-time based on its type (queryable using the `sizeof` operator) and cannot simply change to another type with another size.

Comment: Technically, you are right, if `Base` and `Derived` were the same size, it would be possible to make an in-place modification of the virtual table pointer of `c` in-place to refer to the virtual table of `Derived`, but this is generally not a safe thing to do and is not directly supported by C++. In C++, an object, once fully constructed, remains a fixed type until it is destructed.

Comment: No sorry, i wasn't trying to say I was right- I am just trying to understand what is it the pointer enables for polymorphism? A pointer is just a memory address? Surely without a pointer we still have an object which has a memory address?

Comment: @user997112: But a pointer can change its value so that it holds the address of a different object, possibly of a different class, with a different size.  An object however, cannot change to be a different object.  It cannot change its own address.

Comment: @user997112 the object exists at an address and has a fixed type and size known at compile time which cannot be changed within the semantics of C++. you can't change the type of an object at runtime because it might change the size of the object and it only has the space allocated to it (either on the stack of the heap) when construcfted. technically, you could do it in-place if the sizes and memory layouts were the same, but C++ semantics do not allow this.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley he does have a point though, there's nothing inherently impossible about changing a type at runtime, if the sizes and layouts are compatible (just change the vptr manually)

Comment: So basically, with a pointer it will change the address it is pointing to from the static type to the dynamic type at run-time? Therefore, if we didn't have a pointer we would still be pointing to the static type (the base class) and never be able to gain access to the derived object's virtual functions?

Comment: @user997112 when you call a virtual function on any object (directly or through a reference or pointer), it's always based on the runtime (dynamic) type of that object; however, C++ semantics guarantees that every object variable (not a pointer or reference) in a well-formed program always has the type it was declared as at compile time (this is a design decision). However, a pointer or reference to a type is allowed to point to any object of the declared type or any subtype (this is also a design decision, it's possible they could have made pointers and/or references non-polymorphic)...

Comment: ...so when you call a function through a pointer or reference, the compiler inserts code that checks the actual runtime type (more or less) and executes the correct function. This never happens with an object variable because an object variable is never supposed to change its type. This is just how the object model works and it's a very effective one.

Comment: @StephenLin if you could put all that as an answer I would accept it- because that's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 17):

I found it helpful to understand that a copy constructor is invoked when assigning like this:

```
class Base { };    
class Derived : public Base { };

Derived x; /* Derived type object created */ 
Base y = x; /* Copy is made (using Base's copy constructor), so y really is of type Base. Copy can cause "slicing" btw. */
```

Since y is an actual object of class Base, rather than the original one, functions called on this are Base's functions.

Answer (score 4):

Consider little endian architectures: values are stored low-order-bytes first. So, for any given unsigned integer, the values 0-255 are stored in the first byte of the value. Accessing the low 8-bits of any value simply requires a pointer to it's address.

So we could implement `uint8` as a class. We know that an instance of `uint8` is ... one byte. If we derive from it and produce `uint16`, `uint32`, etc, the *interface* remains the same for purposes of abstraction, but the one most important change is size of the concrete instances of the object.

Of course, if we implemented `uint8` and `char`, the sizes may be the same, likewise `sint8`.

However, `operator=` of `uint8` and `uint16` are going to move different quantities of data.

In order to create a Polymorphic function we must either be able to:

a/ receive the argument by value by copying the data into a new location of the correct size and layout,
b/ take a pointer to the object's location,
c/ take a reference to the object instance,

We can use templates to achieve a, so polymorphism *can* work without pointers and references, but if we are not counting templates, then lets consider what happens if we implement `uint128` and pass it to a function expecting `uint8`? Answer: 8 bits get copied instead of 128.

So what if we made our polymorphic function accept `uint128` and we passed it a `uint8`. If our `uint8` we were copying was unfortunately located, our function would attempt to copy 128 bytes of which 127 were outside of our accessible memory -> crash.

Consider the following:

```
class A { int x; };
A fn(A a)
{
    return a;
}

class B : public A {
    uint64_t a, b, c;
    B(int x_, uint64_t a_, uint64_t b_, uint64_t c_)
    : A(x_), a(a_), b(b_), c(c_) {}
};

B b1 { 10, 1, 2, 3 };
B b2 = fn(b1);
// b2.x == 10, but a, b and c?
```

At the time `fn` was compiled, there was no knowledge of `B`. However, `B` is derived from `A` so polymorphism should allow that we can call `fn` with a `B`. However, the *object* it returns should be an `A` comprising a single int.

If we pass an instance of `B` to this function, what we get back should be just a `{ int x; }` with no a, b, c.

This is "slicing".

Even with pointers and references we don't avoid this for free. Consider:

```
std::vector<A*> vec;
```

Elements of this vector could be pointers to `A` or something derived from `A`. The language generally solves this through the use of the "vtable", a small addition to the object's instance which identifies the type and provides function pointers for virtual functions. You can think of it as something like:

```
template<class T>
struct PolymorphicObject {
    T::vtable* __vtptr;
    T __instance;
};
```

Rather than every object having its own distinct vtable, classes have them, and object instances merely point to the relevant vtable.

The problem now is not slicing but type correctness:

```
struct A { virtual const char* fn() { return "A"; } };
struct B : public A { virtual const char* fn() { return "B"; } };

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    A* a = new A();
    B* b = new B();
    memcpy(a, b, sizeof(A));
    std::cout << "sizeof A = " << sizeof(A)
        << " a->fn(): " << a->fn() << '\n';
}
```

http://ideone.com/G62Cn0

```
sizeof A = 4 a->fn(): B
```

What we should have done is use `a->operator=(b)`

http://ideone.com/Vym3Lp

but again, this is copying an A to an A and so slicing would occur:

```
struct A { int i; A(int i_) : i(i_) {} virtual const char* fn() { return "A"; } };
struct B : public A {
    int j;
    B(int i_) : A(i_), j(i_ + 10) {}
    virtual const char* fn() { return "B"; }
};

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    A* a = new A(1);
    B* b = new B(2);
    *a = *b; // aka a->operator=(static_cast<A*>(*b));
    std::cout << "sizeof A = " << sizeof(A)
        << ", a->i = " << a->i << ", a->fn(): " << a->fn() << '\n';
}
```

http://ideone.com/DHGwun

(`i` is copied, but B's `j` is lost)

The conclusion here is that pointers/references are required because the original instance carries *membership* information with it that copying may interact with.

But also, that polymorphism is not perfectly solved within C++ and one must be cognizant of their obligation to provide/block actions which could produce slicing.

Answer (score 2):

You need pointers or reference because for the kind of polymorphism you are interested in (*), you need that the dynamic type could be different from the static type, in other words that the true type of the object is different than the declared type.  In C++ that happens only with pointers or references.

---

(*) Genericity, the type of polymorphism provided by templates, doesn't need pointers nor references.

Comment: I don't mean to split straws- but I am trying to understand (at a low level I guess) why this part of your message is so: "In C++ that happens on with pointers or references". Why is this the case?

Comment: @user997112 because the point of having object-orientation is to have some static guarantees about object lifetimes and identities. if objects could arbitrarily change runtime types after construction, it would be much harder to maintain invariants about program state.

Comment: @user997112, the object model of C++ doesn't lean that way.

Answer (score 0):

When an object is passed by value, it's typically put on the stack. Putting something on the stack requires knowledge of just how big it is. When using polymorphism, you know that the incoming object implements a particular set of features, but you usually have no idea the size of the object (nor should you, necessarily, that's part of the benefit). Thus, you can't put it on the stack. You do, however, always know the size of a pointer.

Now, not everything goes on the stack, and there are other extenuating circumstances. In the case of virtual methods, the pointer to the object is also a pointer to the object's vtable(s), which indicate where the methods are. This allows the compiler to find and call the functions, regardless of what object it's working with.

Another cause is that very often the object is implemented outside of the calling library, and allocated with a completely different (and possibly incompatible) memory manager. It could also have members that can't be copied, or would cause problems if they were copied with a different manager. There could be side-effects to copying and all sorts of other complications.

The result is that the pointer is the only bit of information on the object that you really properly understand, and provides enough information to figure out where the other bits you need are.

Comment: I won't -1 you but stack vs heap has no relevance here, it just adds to confusion to mention that.