# calling a virtual function through a reference: derived class' override gets called

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-binding

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Parent {
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "Parent" << endl; }
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    void f() { cout << "Child" << endl; }
};

void t1(Parent * p) { p->f(); }
void t2(Parent & p) { p.f(); }

int main() {
    Child a;

    t1(&a);
    t2(a);

    return 0;
}
```

I tested this both in Visual Studio 2013 and [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/xlPEMO), and both got the result:

```
Child
Child
```

I can understand `t1` calling `Child::f()` as the result of dynamic binding, but the second one has me puzzled - I expected the `Parent &` to "fix" the type, so `t2` would call `Parent::f()`.  Am I misunderstanding the rules? How does one explain this behavior?

Comment: That's what is to expect with virtual polymorphism?

Comment: `I expected the Parent & to "fix" the type` What is this expectation based on? Can you point to a piece of documentation that misled you so?

Comment: I know it works on pointers; so references also follow the same rules?

Comment: Yes. Though it looks like you don't completely understand those rules; can we help you?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: it's most likely based on lectures that I didn't completely stay awake in ... : ) I think I need to reread the docs on this

Comment: @martin_ljchan And skip parties at night before attending _important lectures_ on the next morning, next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is what polymorphism does.**

---

> I expected the `Parent &` to "fix" the type, so `t2` would call `Parent::f()`.

Well, you expected wrong.

> Am I misunderstanding the rules?

Yes.

> How does one explain this behavior?

By picking up a book on C++ and reading the chapter on polymorphism.
Your `Parent&` works just as a `Parent*` would: by allowing *virtual dispatch*.

The important thing to note is that **pointers (and references) do not invoke polymorphism**. So wherever you read that only pointers invoke polymorphism was doubly wrong. **Polymorphism is invoked by object access.** It just so happens that, due to [the slicing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/560648), [it is impossible to invoke virtual dispatch *except* through a pointer or reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15188894/560648).

- [Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: On [invoking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188894/why-doesnt-polymorphism-work-without-pointers-references) virtual dispatch

Comment: I must have somehow missed the part about virtual dispatch works for pointers _and references_.  Thanks everyone for the help; the extra reading is also appreciated :)