# How object slicing can result in memory corruption?

Tags: c++, inheritance, d, memory-corruption, object-slicing

The C++ expert & D language creator [Walter Bright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Bright) says that:

> The slicing problem is serious because it can result in memory
>   corruption, and it is very difficult to guarantee a program does not
>   suffer from it. To design it out of the language, classes that support
>   inheritance should be accessible by reference only (not by value). The
>   D programming language has this property.

It would be better if someone explain it by giving an C++ example where object slicing problem causes memory corruption? And how this problem is solved by D language?

Comment: Why don't you [ask the guy in his answer to this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)? Or read the comments.

Comment: @juanchopanza: what's the problem If I ask seperate question? This will be useful in future & easy to search if same question arises to someone in future.

Comment: This is completely wrong. This question is different from the linked one.

Comment: Wat? Read Walter Bright's answer. It has basically the same quote. And not much in the way back-up, but he does give an example (in words, not code unfortunately..)

Comment: Anyway, I re-opened. I don't think the "duplicate" covered this well enough.

Comment: I think there is a code example here you can look at, don't want to reformat it for SO right now though... https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/oop-inheritance-adapted-to-rust/586

Comment: I think Walter is exaggerating by calling this a *serious* problem. Having the derived class set a pointer in the base class, instead of supplying a virtual function, is a *design problem*. Not a language problem.

Answer (score 4):

Consider

```
class Account
{
    char *name = new char[16];

    public: virtual ~Account() { delete[] name; }
    public: virtual void sayHello() { std::cout << "Hello Base\n"; }

};

class BankAccount : public Account
{
    private: char *bankName = new char[16];
    public: virtual ~BankAccount() override { delete[] bankName; }
    public: virtual void sayHello() override { std::cout << "Hello Derived\n"; }

};

int main()
{
    BankAccount d;

    Account a1 = d; // slicing
    Account& a2 = d; // no slicing

    a1.sayHello(); // Hello Base
    a2.sayHello(); // Hello Derived

}
```

Here `a1` will leak `bankName` when `Account::~Account`, instead of `BankAccount::~BankAccount`, runs because it has no way to invoke a polymorphic behavior. As why it is so specifically, it has been greatly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188894/why-doesnt-polymorphism-work-without-pointers-references).

Comment: Why will `a1` leak `bankName`? Will `a1` actually contain `bankName`?

Comment: This answer is not correct, but is still an example of why slicing is bad. The example will not leak memory, because `d` is still destroyed and will free `bankName`. Note, `name` will be freed twice -- once when `a1` is destroyed and once when `d` is destroyed. So this is still an example of unsafe memory usage due to slicing, but this is not a memory leak.

Comment: @William: You're not wrong, clearly 6 years back I wanted to express how slicing can result in memory _corruption_ (i.e. what the OP is asking) but I ended up mixing the terms. Ty for pointing out.

Comment: @William It will be freed twice, yes, but not because of object slicing. If you replace `Account a1 = d` with `BankAccount a1 = d` there would be no more slicing but still be a double-free.

Answer (score 3):

An aspect of inheritance that is difficult to model well is that there are some cases where it's useful to say:

1. A `T` should be assignable to a variable of type `U`.
2. A `*T` should be assignable to a `*U`.
3. A `const *T` should be assignable to a `const *U`.

but C++ makes no distinction among them.  Java and C# avoid the issue by only offering the second semantics (it's not possible to have variables which hold class-object instances; while those languages don't use pointer notation, all class-type variables are implicitly references to objects stored elsewhere).  In C++, however, there's no simple form of declaration which simply allows the second or third form without the first, nor is there any way to distinguish between "pointer to something which can be stored in a variable of type `U`" from "pointer to something which contains all the virtual and non-virtual members of a `U`".  It would be possible for a language's type system to make a distinction between "strict" and "non-strict" pointer types, and allow a virtual method of class `U` to specify that:

1. It must be overridden by any type which cannot be stored in a variable of type `U`, and...
2. Within the method, `this` should be of type as `U strict *`, and dereferencing a variable of type `U strict *` should yield an rvalue of type `U strict`, which should be assignable to one of type `U` even though an rvalue of type `U` would not be.

C++ offers no such distinction, however, which means that there is no way to distinguish between methods that require a pointer to something that can be stored in a variable of type `U`, versus those which require something that has the same members.

Answer (score 2):

The following simple little C++ program with its output shows the slicing problem and why it can lead to memory corruption.

With languages like D and Java and C# the variables are accessed through a reference handle. This means that all of the information about the variable is associated with the reference handle. With C++ the information about the variable is part of the compiler state when the compile is being done. Turning on C++ Run-Time Type Information (RTTI) can provide a mechanism to look at object type at run time however it doesn't really help with the slicing problem.

Basically, C++ removes a safety net in order to squeeze out a bit more speed.

The C++ compiler has a set of rules that it uses so that if specific methods are not provided in a class, for instance copy constructor or assignment operator, the compiler will do its best to create its own, default version. The compiler also has rules it uses so that if a specific method is not available then it will look for an alternative way of creating the code that will express the meaning of a source statement.

Sometimes the compiler is too helpful and the result becomes dangerous.

In this example, there are two classes, `levelOne` is the base class and `levelTwo` is the derived class. It uses virtual destructors so that a pointer to an object of the base class will clean up the derived class part of the object as well.

In the output we see that the assignment of the derived class to the base class results in slicing and when the destructor is called, only the destructor for the base class is called and not the destructor of the derived class.

The result of the destructor of the derived class not being called means that any resources owned by the derived object may not be released properly.

Here is the simple program.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class levelOne
{
public:
    levelOne(int i = 1) : iLevel(i) { iMyId = iId++; std::cout << "  levelOne construct  " << iMyId << std::endl; }
    virtual ~levelOne() { std::cout << "  levelOne destruct  " << iMyId << "  iLevel = " << iLevel << std::endl; }

    int  iLevel;
    int  iMyId;

    static int iId;
};

int levelOne::iId = 1;

class levelTwo : public levelOne
{
public:
    levelTwo(int i = 2) : levelOne(i) { jLevel = 2; iMyTwoId = iTwoId++;  std::cout << "     levelTwo construct  " << iMyId << ", " << iMyTwoId << std::endl; }
    virtual ~levelTwo() { std::cout << "     levelTwo destruct  " << iMyId << ", " << iMyTwoId << "  iLevel = " << iLevel << "  jLevel = " << jLevel << std::endl; }

    int  jLevel;
    int  iMyTwoId;

    static int iTwoId;
};

int levelTwo::iTwoId = 101;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    levelOne one;
    levelTwo two;

    std::cout << "Create LevelOne and assign to it a LevelTwo" << std::endl;
    levelOne aa;     // create a levelOne object
    aa = two;        // assign to the levelOne object a levelTwo object

    std::cout << "Create LevelTwo and assign to it a LevelOne pointer then delete it" << std::endl;
    levelOne *pOne = new levelTwo;
    delete pOne;

    std::cout << "Exit program." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output shows that the object created with the `pOne = new levelTwo;` whose id is `4` hits both the `levelTwo` and the `levelOne` destructors properly handling the object destruction.

However the assignment of the `levelTwo` object `two` to the `levelOne` object `aa` results in slicing since the default assignment operator, which just does a memory copy, is used so that when the destructor of object `aa` is invoked, only the destructor of `levelOne` is performed meaning that any resources owned by the derived class will not be released.

Then the other two objects are destructed properly as they all go out of scope as the program ends. Reading this log remember that destructors are called in the reverse order of construction.

```
  levelOne construct  1
  levelOne construct  2
     levelTwo construct  2, 101
Create LevelOne and assign to it a LevelTwo
  levelOne construct  3
Create LevelTwo and assign to it a LevelOne pointer then delete it
  levelOne construct  4
     levelTwo construct  4, 102
     levelTwo destruct  4, 102  iLevel = 2  jLevel = 2
  levelOne destruct  4  iLevel = 2
Exit program.
  levelOne destruct  2  iLevel = 2
     levelTwo destruct  2, 101  iLevel = 2  jLevel = 2
  levelOne destruct  2  iLevel = 2
  levelOne destruct  1  iLevel = 1
```

Comment: After assigning a LevelTwo to a LevelOne, the LevelTwo still exists and is destructed properly. The LevelOne only has member variables for the shared portion, and that is all that is copied over (otherwise you'd corrupt the stack). So the example you give is actually fine. Wikipedia has a [better example of the slicing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)