# Wrapped Type Casting

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, casting

Can someone please help me to understand why this code compiles:

```
class A {};

class B : public A {};

void foo( A ) {}


int main() {
  B b;

  foo( b );
}
```

but this not:

```
class A {};

class B : public A {};

template< typename T >
class wrapper {};

void foo( wrapper<A> ) {}

int main() {
  wrapper<B> b;

  foo( b );
}
```

The only difference in the second code (i.e., the code that does not compile) is that the classes `A` and `B` are wrapped as template parameters in the class `wrapper`; the wrapping, surprisingly, seems to hinder the conversion from `B` to `A`.

It would also be great if someone can help me to fix the second code.

Comment: wrapper <A> and wrapper <B> are two completely unrelated types

Comment: `wrapper<A>` and `wrapper<B>` have no direct inheritance relation.

Comment: For what it's worth, for less trivial examples your first version will exhibit [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) and [will not act polymorphically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188894/why-doesnt-polymorphism-work-without-pointers-references)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class B` is derived from `class A`, so each `B` *is* an `A` and can be used in its place. However, `wrapper<A>` has no relationship with `wrapper<B>` - why would it?

Consider this example: if B is the son of A, would B’s wife be the son of A’s wife (obviously not - they have no relation).

To accomplish such a relation, you would need to derive `wrapper<B>` from `wrapper<A>`, which is not possible with `wrapper<>` being a template class. Consider other approaches, where you send `B` into the methods of the `wrapper<A>` class or similar (works, as it *is* a `A`).

Comment: I suppose we should all just be glad that A is not a son of a B.