# Abstract class on top of Eigen's Matrix and Vector

Tags: c++, abstract-class, eigen

I would like to implement a neural network framework consisting of layers which can then be composed into a computational graph (see for example [caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.cpp)). I am using the eigen library for matrices. Eigen distinguishes between vectors and matrices so that for some operations (adding a bias to a matrix) only a vector can be used (and not a matrix with the same dimensions as the vector). For example:

```
MatrixXf A = MatrixXf(3, 2); // Variables not initialized for brevity
VectorXf v = VectorXf(2);
MatrixXf R1 = A.array().rowwise() + v.transpose().array();  // Broadcasts v correctly
MatrixXf vMat = MatrixXf(1, 2);
MatrixXf R2 = A.array().rowwise() + vMat.array();           // YOU_TRIED_CALLING_A_VECTOR_METHOD_ON_A_MATRIX Error
```

If I want the layers to look something like this:

```
void AffineForward(std::vector<Tensor> in, std::vector<Tensor> out)
{
   MatrixXf &X = in[0];
   MatrixXf &W = in[1];
   VectorXf &b = in[2];

   out[0] = X * W;
   out[0] += b;
}
```

how would I design the abstract Tensor class so that I can just send in a std::vector of Tensors? I thought about something like this:

```
class Tensor
{
public:
    virtual Tensor operator*(const Tensor &t) const = 0;
};

class TensorMatrix : Tensor
{
 public:
    TensorMatrix operator*(const TensorMatrix &t) const;
    TensorMatrix operator*(const TensorVector &t) const;
    MatrixXf _data;
};

class TensorVector : Tensor
{
 public:
    VectorXf _data;
};
```

but the virtual Tensor operator* throws a compile time error (function returning abstract class Tensor is not allowed) which makes sense.

What is the easiest way of doing what I want? Creating some class that could be put into a container and I could get both MatrixXf and VectorXf out of it (depending on what the user put in?). Caffe uses something called 'Blob'.

Comment: [polymorphism won't work without using pointers or references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188894/why-doesnt-polymorphism-work-without-pointers-references) so this design won't work as written

Comment: you can avoid returning an abstract type if you can live with overloading `operator*=` instead

Comment: did you take a look at Eigen tensor module ?

Comment: "Eigen distinguishes between vectors and matrices so that for some operations (adding a bias to a matrix) only a vector can be used" this seems wrong to me, can you make an example ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I edited my question. I didn't want to use the tensor module since I've seen that it's not yet very well supported.

Comment: your example doesn't work because broadcasting needs compile time bounds in order to work; so, you just need to be more explicit: eg vMat.row(0); moreover, why the array() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Eigen distinguishes between vectors and matrices so that for some operations (adding a bias to a matrix) only a vector can be used (and not a matrix with the same dimensions as the vector).

this is not true, a vector *is* a matrix in Eigen; it's just that some operations require dimensions to be known at compile time; in your example

```
MatrixXf R1 = A.rowwise() + v.transpose();
MatrixXf R2 = A.rowwise() + vMat;
```

the second line does not compile because that broadcasting needs a matrix with a compile time row-dimensions == 1;
the solution is to tell Eigen you want a row vector explictly:

```
MatrixXf R2 = A.rowwise() + vMat.row(0);
```

a code working with both row and column vectors stored as MatrixXf being something like ( whether this advisable or not depending on your ultimate requirements )

```
if( vMat.rows() == 1  )
  MatrixXf R1 = A.rowwise() + vMat.rows(0); ...
else if( vMat.cols() == 1  )
  MatrixXf R2 = A.rowwise() + vMat.transpose().rows(0); ...
else
  whatever...
```

so, you can always store vectors as matrices with Eigen, you just need some care in telling Eigen what to do with them ...