# placement new with derived class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, undefined-behavior, placement-new, vptr

C++ gurus. Need your help with this little head scratcher:

```
#include <iostream>
struct B{
    virtual ~B() = default;
    virtual void talk() { std::cout << "Be-e-e\n"; }
};

struct D:B{
    void talk() override { std::cout << "Duh\n"; }
    ~D() { std::cout << "~D()\n"; }
};

int main(){
    B b{};      // vptr points to B
    new (&b) D; // vptr now points to D
    b.talk();   // "Be-e-e" (why? shouldn't the vptr be used?)
    b = D{};    // "~D()" (why? shouldn't the copying be elided?)
    b.talk();   // "Be-e-e"

    B*b1{new D};
    b1->talk(); // "Duh"
    delete b1;  // "~D()"

    return 0;
}
```

The code is pretty straightforward: have a base object on stack, placement-new a derived one into it (yes, eeew, but bear with me) and calling a virtual method, expecting a derived's output to be printed.

### Actual output

The code above produces the following output:

```
Be-e-e
~D()
Be-e-e
Duh
~D()
```

That behavior is universally observed on MSVC, gcc, clang, and a few online compilers I tried it on (which is an extremely strong indication that it is I who am wrong).

### Part 1

The placement-new re-news a derived-type object into the base-type memory. And that updates the vptr to point to the derived-type's vtable (directly observed in the debugger).

**Main question**: is that the expected behavior? (I want to say "yes" so if it is not - please explain to me)

I want to believe that performing a placement-new (provided there's enough memory for the derived-type object) should in-place initialize a brand new object of the derived-type.

---

If my understanding is correct, the first `b.talk()` should output `"Duh"` as the object now is of derived-type. Why is it still printing `"Be-e-e"`?

Assigning a derived-type object into the base-type object (in addition to causing object splicing) does not copy the vptr, so that second `"Be-e-e"` output is expected, provided the object is still of the base-type when we get to that line of code.

### Part 2

Why is there a `~D()` call in the `b = D{};` assignment? Isn't it a temporary that should be copy-elided with no need for a destructor call on that temporary?

### Part 3

The last block of code that uses pointers works "as expected" and is just here for sanity check

Comment: Virtual calls only work through pointers and references. Not on direct objects.

Comment: Also I think you have some undefined behavior in a couple of places there.

Comment: I think this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188894/why-doesnt-polymorphism-work-without-pointers-references

Comment: `b = D{};`, also, in fact, is wrong, since derived classes can use the base class's constructor but not the opposite... (Here, b is the base class and can **only** use its own constructor...

Comment: @Ruks "_derived classes can use the base class's constructor but not the opposite_" What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code:

```
B b{};      // vptr points to B
new (&b) D; // vptr now points to D
```

This is a potential problem for two reasons. First you did not call the *destructor* for the base object `B`. Second the size of `B` could be too small to accommodate a `D` type object.

```
b.talk();   // "Be-e-e" (why? shouldn't the vptr be used?)
```

Virtual calls only work when calling through a pointer or a reference. A direct function call like this never uses *virtual dispatch*.

```
b = D{};    // "~D()" (why? shouldn't the copying be elided?)
```

Because `b` is declared as type `B` and you can not elide a copy between different types like `D` and `B`.

Comment: "_First you did not call the destructor for the base object B._" There is no reason to: that particular destructor has no functional effect.

Comment: @curiousguy The destructor may not have a *functional effect* with respect to the program but there is no telling how it affects the internal state of the compiler and its decision making process. It is still *undefined behavior* if the destructor is not called.

Comment: "_It is still undefined behavior_" since when?