# Change Object type based on inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the class Person:

```
class Person {
public:
    int Age;
    int ID;
};
```

And I have 2 classes: Adult and Child that inherit Person:

```
class Child : Person{
public:
    Child();
    void print_ms_child(){
        cout << "I'm an child";
    }
};

class Adult : Person{
public:
    Adult(); 
    void print_ms_Adult(){
        cout << "I'm an adult";
    }
};
```

I want to declare a Person Object

```
int main() {
    Person my_Person;
    my_Person.Age = 10;
    my_Person.ID = 013272;
```

And then use conditions to set its type.

```
    if(my_Person.Age > 18){
        my_Person = new Adult(); // this won't work
    }
    else{
        my_Person = new Child(); // this won't work
    }
```

I suppose it it's posible but I don't know the right syntax for doing it (***How do I do that?***). (Sorry for posting code that won't even compile)

***But* also**, I want to change from Child to Adult in case the Age changes (I'm not even sure that's possible).

```
    my_Person.Age = 21;
    my_Person = new Adult(); // this won't work
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't polymorphism work without pointers/references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188894/why-doesnt-polymorphism-work-without-pointers-references)

Comment: Since you are using `new` which returns a *pointer* to an object, not the object itself, it seems to me that you simply intended `my_Person` to be a `Person*`, not `Person`. Otherwise, how could `new` work with it in the first place, inheritance and polymorphism aside? Also note that you need to make a *virtual* interface (especially a `virtual` destructor) in order to use the derived classes through the base class pointer.

Comment: Also, you should not use `new` in modern C++. You can use `std::make_unique` together with `std::unique_ptr` instead, which will correctly `delete` the pointer for you, so you don't forget it or accidentally double-delete.

Comment: If your classes are really this simple, why don't you just have a `bool isAdult() const;` member function of `Person` and not use the derived classes?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm this is just an example to, I want to make this to more complicated classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first define your class `Person` like this instead:

```
class Person {
    int Age;
    int ID;
protected:
   Person(int age, int id): Age{age}, ID{id} {}
public:
   virtual ~Person() = default;
};
```

That is, `Person`'s constructor is made `protected` so that a class outside the hierarchy can't create a `Person` object, and its destructor is made `virtual` to make it suitable as a base class for a polymorphic type.

Then, both `Child` and `Adult` publicly inherit from `Person`, as you already have them. Their constructors end up calling `Person`'s constructor with the same parametrization their constructors receive:

```
class Adult: public Person {
public:
   Adult(int age, int id): Person(age, id) {}
   // ...
};

class Child: public Person {
public:
   Child(int age, int id): Person(age, id) {}
   // ...
};
```

Finally, for creating objects that derived from `Person`, I would create the *factory function* below:

```
std::unique_ptr<Person> create_person(int age, int id) {
   if (age < 18)
      return std::make_unique<Child>(age, id);
   else
      return std::make_unique<Adult>(age, id);
}
```

This factory function creates a `Child` object if the to-create person's age is under 18. Otherwise, it creates an `Adult` object. This – determining the type of the object to create – is done at run time.

---

**EDIT:** You wondered how a `Child` object could become an `Adult` object after its age has reached 18 years old.

I would suggest making the state of a `Person` object *immutable* so that a fresh new object has to be created every time the age of a person is increased. This way, creating a new object from an existing one will be the only way to grow a `Person`'s age and, at that moment, you will have the control to decide whether to create a `Child` or `Adult` object based on the new age.

For doing this, first, qualify the `Age` data member in `Person` as `const` (you can do the same with `ID`). Then, define the following `Person`'s member function which always creates a new object (with the same `ID`) resulting from increasing a `Person`'s object `Age` by one:

```
std::unique_ptr<Person> Person::increase_age() const {
   return create_person(Age + 1, ID);
}
```

As you see, it delegates the creation of the object to the factory function, `create_person()`, already explained above. This member function can be called on both `Child` and `Adult` objects since it inherits from `Person`.

Comment: Thank you! this is very useful. But then I wonder if, once we have an Object Child, can we change it's age and therefor it should be an Adult

Comment: @Ivan you could, for example, create a member function in `Child` called `increase_age()`. Such a function could return an `std::unique_ptr<Person>` as well  – a new object resulting from the age increment. This would follow the same principle as the *factory function above*: if the new age is still lower than 18, then you create a `Child`, otherwise, an `Adult`. In both cases, you use the new age and the `ID` of the current object. I hope it helps

Comment: @Ivan I've edited the answer with the information I've explained to you. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the type of a variable after its declaration. C++ is a *statically typed language*. `my_person` is a `Person`. You cannot change that.