# Why do you need to return a pointer to take advantage of covariance?

Tags: c++

I have a super class `Block` and a derived class `LLeftPiece`.

Block.h

```
class Block
{

public:
  Block();
  ~Block();
  virtual Block* rotate(){}; //override
};
```

LLeftPiece.h

```
class LLeftPiece : public Block
{
public:
    static const BLOCK_COLOR color = COLOR_WHITE;
    LLeftPiece* rotate() override; 
    LLeftPiece();
    LLeftPiece(const LLeftPiece &obj); 
    ~LLeftPiece(); 
};
```

I have a virtual function rotate which I want to return a new copy of the block but rotated. In my case I return a pointer to this new piece. I would rather just return an instance of `LLeftPiece` but the compiler complains saying it does not have covariance with `Block`. When I return a pointer it works fine. Why do I need to return a pointer instead of just an instance of the class?

Essentially I am asking why isn't `virtual Block rotate()` valid?

Comment: Closely related: [Why doesn't polymorphism work without pointers/references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15188894/978917)

Comment: `virtual Block rotate()` is valid. `virtual Block rotate() override` is not, because it's an overload. It's not overriding.

Comment: @ruakh good read, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> C++ Why do you need to return a pointer to take advantage of covariance?

This is not quite accurate. Pointer is not necessary if you instead use a reference. In other words: *Indirection* is necessary for covariance. More generally, indirection is necessary for any runtime polymorphism.

A value of type `LLeftPiece` is *not* a value of type `Block`. This may be confusing to those coming from object oriented languages that do not have value semantics and where indirection is implicit. `LLeftPiece*` is a pointer that points to an object that has a base subobject of type `Block`, and `LLeftPiece*` implicitly converts to `Block*`, which allows covariance to work.

Comment: I guess Java has spoiled me over the last couple years. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin To understand some differences between Java and C++, it is important to remember that all variables of class types in Java are actually pointers underneath.