# How to access methods and attributes that are specific to derived classes when talking about objects inside a vector?

Tags: c++

I am building a simple chess application and I've been finding some issues. Here is my problem:

I have a class Piece:

```
class Piece {
protected:
    std::string name; // this is to store the piece's name (bishop, rook, etc.)
public:
    Piece();
    int positionX;
    int positionY;
    std::string getName();
};
```

And I also have a class Board, which has a 8x8 matrix of Pieces:

```
class Board {
public:
    // the construct fills the matrix with instances from Piece just so all matrix slots will have a piece
    Board();
    void showBoard();
    std::vector<std::vector<Piece>> piece;
    void place(Piece piece, char positionY, int positionX);
};
```

At the moment, I have a board object with 64 generic Pieces.

Now, I created a class Rook, which inherits from Piece:

```
class Rook: public Piece {
private:
    std::string color;
public:
    Rook(std::string color);
    std::string getColor();
    bool isRook = true; // dummy attribute just to show you my problem
};
```

And now I try to place my rook inside my pieces matrix:

```
Board board;
Rook rook = Rook("white");
rook.positionX = 3;
rook.positionY = 0;
board.piece.at(rook.positionX).at(rook.positionY) = rook;

std::cout << board.piece.at(3).at(0).positionX << std::endl; // as expected, this outputs 3
```

Finally, here comes my actual issue:

When I try to access something that only rook has, and not the other pieces, for example the bool isRook, it throws an error that Piece class has no attribute isRook:

```
std::cout << board.piece.at(3).at(0).isRook << std::endl; // this throws an error "class Piece has no attribute isRook"
```

I assume this is because I have a matrix of Pieces, so I can't access things that are specific to Rooks. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `class Piece` doesn't have `isRook` attribute, it is only available in the `Rook` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to have a polymorphic vector, you need to use a vector of pointers like so:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Piece*>> piece;
```

Then you can add different derived objects to the vector like:

```
piece.push_back(new Rook("white"));
piece.push_back(new Bishop("white"));
```

You also should use a virtual destructor in the base class:

```
virtual ~Piece();
```

And set the destructor in the board class to handle the new objects accordingly when the board object is destructed:

```
~Board(){
   for(Piece* p: piece){
      delete p;
   }
}
```

Now, this is using raw pointers, maybe a better way to go about it is to use [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one).

Answer (score 1):

The thing is: Either you use polymorphism or you don't. Something in between is possible but adds complications. Having a container of base class pointers and wanting to access an object as a child class is a design smell. You fix it by providing the method in the base class:

```
class Piece {
protected:
    std::string name; // this is to store the piece's name (bishop, rook, etc.)
public:
    Piece();
    int positionX;
    int positionY;
    std::string getName();
    bool isRook();                   // all Pieces have a isRook()
    virtual ~Piece();                // virtual destructor !
};
```

Also note that `Piece` was missing a virtual destructor. Last but not least you need a vector of pointers to make use of polymorphism. Currently you have object slicing. Read more on that here: [Why doesn't polymorphism work without pointers/references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188894/why-doesnt-polymorphism-work-without-pointers-references)