# gmock, Expected: to be called once Actual: never called

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
using ::testing::AtLeast;
using ::testing::Return;
using ::testing::_;

class User{
public:
    string Name;
    virtual void SetName(string tmpName){Name=tmpName;}
    virtual string GetName(){return Name;}
    virtual bool IsAdmin(){ 
        string admin="alley";
        if(admin.compare(Name)==0)//the contents of both strings are equal
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};

class MockUser:public User
{
    public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(SetName, void(string tmpName));
    MOCK_METHOD0(GetName, string());
    MOCK_METHOD0(IsAdmin, bool());
};

class Reservation{
public:
    User &BookName;
    Reservation(User user):BookName(user){}
    bool CanBeCancelBy(User cuser){
        cuser.IsAdmin();
        if(cuser.IsAdmin()==true)
            return true;
        if(cuser.GetName().compare(BookName.GetName())==0)//the contents of both strings are equal
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};
TEST(CanBeCancelBy, MockUserIsAdmin_ReturnTrue)
{
    //Arrange   
    MockUser admin;
    User a1;
    a1.SetName("a1");
    Reservation r1(a1);
    EXPECT_CALL(admin, IsAdmin()).Times(1).WillOnce(Return(true));
    //Act
    //bool result =admin.IsAdmin();
    bool result=r1.CanBeCancelBy(admin);
    //Assert
    EXPECT_EQ(result, 1);
}

int main()
{   
    testing::InitGoogleTest();
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I think IsAdmin() will be called, but it doesn't.

The execute result as bellow:

[ RUN      ] [mCanBeCancelBy.MockUserIsAdmin_ReturnTrue
Reservation.cpp:56: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
   result
    Which is: false
  1
Reservation.cpp:51: Failure
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(admin, IsAdmin())...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
[  FAILED  ] [mCanBeCancelBy.MockUserIsAdmin_ReturnTrue (3 ms)

Can someone help me to understand what's going wrong?

Comment: If I modify like this,

bool result =admin.IsAdmin();

//bool result=r1.CanBeCancelBy(admin);

unit test will be success.

Comment: Polymorphism in C++ only works when you are using *pointers* or *references*. `CanBeCancelBy` *always* takes an object of type `User` and nothing else. When you pass a derived class there, it gets sliced to a regular class of `User` type. Looking for a good duplicate now.

Comment: [Why doesn't polymorphism work without pointers/references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188894/why-doesnt-polymorphism-work-without-pointers-references) [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: Also, `BookName` is a dangling reference as soon as constructor finishes. You cannot ever use it outside of constructor, because the object it refers to is dead.

Comment: Test success when I modify like that
bool CanBeCancelBy(User &user)
thanks.