# Using different derived class member in 2 objects of another class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base class A and 2 derived classes A1 and A2. 
There is another class X and I created 2 objects obj_x1, obj_x2 from this class X. I want to use derived class A1 in obj_x1 and derived class A2 in obj_x2.

How can i declare this class A object in class X so that i can use corresponding derived class objects in obj_x1 and obj_x2 instances?

```html
class A {
  public:
  virtual void print() {
      printf("I AM A\n");
  };
};

class A1 : public A {
  public:
    void print();
};

class A2 : public A {
public:
  void print();
};


void
A1::print
()
{
  printf("I AM A1\n");
}

void
A2::print
()
{
   printf("I AM A2\n");
}

class X
{
     // problem:I want A to be A1 for obj_x1 and A2 for obj_x2 instance
     A a;
   public:
     void which_a();
};

void
X::which_a() {
  a.print();
}

int main() {
    X obj_x1;
    X obj_x2;
    obj_x1.which_a();  // I want member a in obj_X1 to be class A1
    obj_x2.which_a();  // I want member a in obj_X2 to be class A2
}
```

Comment: A piece of code is the best way to explain what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Having read through your problem a few times I think what you need is polymorphism:

```
class X
{
public:
  void set (std::unique_ptr<A> a) { _a = std::move(a); }
private:
  std::unique_ptr<A> _a = nullptr;
};
```

Then you can set _a to be an instance of A1 or A2 by passing in a pointer (unique pointer in my example) to A. If that's not what you're after then you probably need to share more details about your specific problem.

Response to edit: thanks for the update to your question. The reason why your sample code won't work is that the data member is a plain object - you will always have an instance of A and there's no way to change that. To drive this point home, if you were to make A abstract by adding a pure virtual method, you would get a compiler error along the lines of *cannot instantiate abstract class.* Meaning I'm trying to create an instance of A, but cannot.

Storing as a pointer is the answer here. You could use raw pointers if you want, but I would recommend a smart pointer as per my example. Storing a pointer to A means that it can be a derived instance of A. Calling a->print() as in your example will then have the desired effect.

It's probably worth reading up on polymorphism if this is new to you. Also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15190540/1618009) explains why you need to use pointers/references to exploit polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks, I added a snippet of code to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer. If it's not clear, let me know and I'll update the example code to be more complete