# Overridden function does not reflect in the base class, is this a normal behavior?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, derived-class, base-class

Given the following code:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void Test() {
        cout << "Not Overridden" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void Test() override {
        cout << "Overridden" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Base o = Derived();
    o.Test();
    return 0;
}
```

Someone like me who is from a Java background, expects the compiler to output `Overridden` but surprisingly the output is exactly the otherwise.

If this is a normal behavior, then what's the point of inheritance in C++ at all?

What is that I am missing?

Comment: Look up "object slicing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's normal behavior, polymorphism only works with pointers and references.

**With raw pointer:**

```
int main() {
    Base* o = new Derived();
    o->Test();
    delete o; //when done with using it delete it from memory
    //...
}
```

An alternative to this memory management would be to use [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/106508/6865932).

**With smart pointer:**

```
int main() {
    unique_ptr<Base> o(new Derived); // automatic memory management
    o->Test();
    //...
}
```

**With reference:**

```
int main() {
    Derived d;
    Base& o = d;
    o.Test();
    //...
}
```

This is something you need to be careful with, when the block where `Derived` object was declared goes out of scope, the reference will be rendered useless, for example, if you return it from a function.

**Output:**

```
Overridden
```

Some threads on the site explain why this is so, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15188894/6865932).

The way you have it leads to [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/6865932).

You'll also want to add a [virtual destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors) to your base class.

Comment: It was probably done that way because C did it that way, i.e. both languages pass by value by default and require you to opt-in to passing by reference. Arguably that makes as much if not more sense as passing by reference by default and having to opt-in to passing values, or having no way to do so (like certain other languages!)

Answer (score 2):

```
Base o = Derived();
```

`o` above is an *object* – a **`Base`** object – not a `Derived` one. The `o` object is created from a `Derived` object by means of [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing), but `o` is still a `Base` object. There is no dynamic dispatch here, so `o.Test()` results in `Base::Test()` being called.

Instead, if you declare `o` as a `Base` pointer that refers to the `Derived` object you create:

```
Base* o = new Derived();
o->Test();
```

In this case, `o` is a *pointer* to an object – as opposed to an object – and dynamic dispatch takes effect: Even though `o` is a pointer to a `Base` object, it is bound to a `Derived` object, so `o->Test()` results in `Derived::Test()` being called this time due to dynamic dispatch.

Analogously if `o` is a reference to `Base` instead of a pointer.

Comment: Since I upvoted your answer I needed to make that correction, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @anastaciu Thank you very much for the correction. I just removed the relevant code from `main()` so that I don't need to add the statement `delete o;` as well. I think it's clearer like this because it's more concise.