# Getting an identifer is undefined issue C++

Tags: c++

I want to make it so my program will create an object based on user input. When I run the program I get the error "identifier "plant" is undefined" on the first call of plant which is "while(plant.getDays() > 0){".

```
#include "Carrot.h"
#include "Potato.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int gameState = 1;
    cout << "WELCOME TO THE CROP GAME" << endl;
    while(gameState == 1){
        cout << endl << "PICK A CROP TO GROW" << endl;
        cout << "1:CARROT - SHORT" << endl;
        cout << "2:POTATO - LONG" << endl;
        int userGameChoice;
        
        cin >> userGameChoice;
        while(userGameChoice < 1 || userGameChoice > 2){
            if(userGameChoice == 1){
                Carrot plant;
                cout << "YOU HAVE CHOSEN TO GROW CARROTS" << endl;
            }
            else if(userGameChoice == 2){
                Potato plant;
                cout << "YOU HAVE CHOSEN TO GROW POTATOES" << endl;
            }
            else{
                cout << "INVALID CHOICE" << endl; 
                cin >> userGameChoice;
            }
            
        } 
        
        while(plant.getDays() > 0){
            int userChoice;
            //STATS
            plant.DisplayStats();
            //MENU
            plant.Menu();
```

Comment: Both `plant` objects you're using in this code have scope-lifetime of their surrounding `{ }`. They don't exist by the time you get to `plant.getDays()`. In short, there is no `plant` by then.

Comment: Maybe relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188894/why-doesnt-polymorphism-work-without-pointers-references

Answer (score 1):

You declare variables `plant` in nested code blocks, so they cannot be seen in the outside blocks, they are visible only in the specific branches of `if-else` statement. When the compiler gets to your `while` loop, there is no visible variable.

If you want it to work, you need to declare variable before you use them in a  visible scope, like:

```
int main(){
    int gameState = 1;
    cout << "WELCOME TO THE CROP GAME" << endl;
    while(gameState == 1){
        cout << endl << "PICK A CROP TO GROW" << endl;
        cout << "1:CARROT - SHORT" << endl;
        cout << "2:POTATO - LONG" << endl;
        int userGameChoice;

        Plant *plant;
        
        cin >> userGameChoice;
        while(userGameChoice < 1 || userGameChoice > 2){
            if(userGameChoice == 1){
                plant = new Carrot()
                cout << "YOU HAVE CHOSEN TO GROW CARROTS" << endl;
            }
            else if(userGameChoice == 2){
                plant = new Potato()
                cout << "YOU HAVE CHOSEN TO GROW POTATOES" << endl;
            }
            else{
                cout << "INVALID CHOICE" << endl; 
                cin >> userGameChoice;
            }
            
        } 
        
        while(plant->getDays() > 0){
            int userChoice;
            //STATS
            plant->DisplayStats();
            //MENU
            plant->Menu();
        }
        delete plant;
    }
}
```

However, if you want it to work, Carrot and Potato need to be descendants of some `Plant` class. Here, `plant` is a pointer to object of class `Plant` and the object is created dynamically, using `new` keyword inside of the `if-else` branches. Since it's created dynamically, it also needs to be deleted after all. You probably need to understand more about polymorphism in C++, the source linked in your comments might be useful for you.

Comment: if you really want it to 'work' the syntax for the member access would be using `plant->` rather than `plant.`. The above code, which won't compile without that fix. And `delete *plant;` is wrong too; it should be `delete plant;`.

Comment: Ahh, yes, you're right, I've written it too quickly. I'll edit it. Those are the C++ syntax details that I always forget and just remember about them after the first compilation.