# What are the benefits of specifying the Type to be higher than the Object Type?

Tags: c++, inheritance

The following C++ code demonstrates what I mean in more detail.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Animal
{
    public:
        int animal_property = 20;
};

class Cat: public Animal
{
    public:
        int cat_property = 10;
};

void test(Cat c)
{
    cout << "Inside test" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Animal hybrid = Cat();
    // cout << hybrid.cat_property << endl;    -- Breaks
    // cout << test(hybrid) << endl;           -- Breaks
    return 0;
}
```

In this example I have created a `Cat()` object, but limited its type visibility to `Animal`. This means I can no longer access any properties or functions on the `Cat` class, despite originally defining it as `Cat()`. I cannot also pass the object to a function which requires a `Cat`.

What are the benefits of doing this and how does it differ to simply comparing it to `Animal animal = Animal()`, are their any design patterns where this is useful?

Comment: have a look at the concept of polymorphism

Comment: "but limited its type visibility to Animal" No you did not. You have actually [sliced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) your object. There is *no* `Cat`, as opposed to "there is a `Cat` I have no access to". See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188894/why-doesnt-polymorphism-work-without-pointers-references)

Comment: If you really want to create a cat and limit the visibility, you need to use `Cat cat; Animal& hybrid = cat;` or `Animal&& hybrid = Cat();`. Otherwise you just call the copy-constructor of `Animal` with a temporary `Cat` as argument.

Comment: `Animal hybrid = Cat();` is similar to `int x = Cat().animal_property;`. A temporary cat is created but then quickly destroyed. At the end only an object of type `Animal` survives.

Comment: @DanielA.White Could I please ask for a specific link for this specific use case. Most polymorphism articles I read just describe the basic concept of a derived class behaving differently, not how slicing relates to it. Thanks.

Comment: Slicing is not related to polymorphism at all. Slicing is nearly universally bad. I cannot think of any legitimate use case. Unfortunately C++ allows slicing by default and with no warning. Seasoned programmers know that polymorphic classes *should be non-copyable*. No copying, no slicing.

Answer (score 1):

> In this example I have created a Cat() object, but limited its type visibility to Animal.

To be more precise, you created a temporary `Cat` object, and then initialised an object of type `Animal` using the temporary. The temporary cat object no longer exists after the initialisation of the `Animal` variable. There was no limitation in "visibility".

> What are the benefits of doing this

You're copying the `Animal` base object from the `Cat` object. If that's something you need to do, then the benefit of doing this is that you achieve your goal.

> are their any design patterns where this is useful?

I don't know of any common patterns doing this. I could imagine an obscure use case of augmenting a C language struct with member functions by inheriting it in which case you can still pass the base into C functions like this. But I'm not sure if it's the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of definition for a variable is sometimes useful, but the real use is in function arguments like `const Animal& a` which is a much more common pattern.

Having function parameters of a more generic base type means these functions can be used by a wider number of derived classes.

Often these arguments are captured into properties that are, likewise, the more generic base for similar reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It lets you, for example, do this:

```
void add_new_animal(std::vector<Animal *> &animals, AnimalSelection selection)
{
    switch (selection)
    {
    case AnimalSelection::dog:
        animals.push_back(new dog());
        break;
    case AnimalSelection::cat:
        animals.push_back(new cat());
        break;
    }
}
```