# dynamic casting from Base class in C++

Tags: c++

Say I've got the following code:

```
class A {};

class B : public A {
public:
    explicit B(string s) {}

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const B &b) {
        out << "b";
        return out;
    }
};

class C : public A {
public:
    explicit C(int i) {}

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const C &c) {
        out << "c";
        return out;
    }
};
```

Then, I have a function like this:

```
A s(int i) {
    if (i == 0)
        return dynamic_cast<B>(B("hello world")); // first try
    else {
        return C(12); // second try
    }
}
```

In main, I write the followings:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << *(s(0)) << endl; // should print "b"
    cout << *(s(1)) << endl; // should print "c"
    return 0;
}
```

How can I do it? (any answer should work for C++14)

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Dynamic casts require RTTI being available, which is only the case for virtual classes. Add a virtual destructor to `A` and you should be able to cast as you want.

Comment: `s` return an (sliced) `A`, returning `std::unique_ptr<A>` would avoid the slicing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188894/why-doesnt-polymorphism-work-without-pointers-references

Comment: Doing a `dynamic_cast` from `B` to `B` is pointless. That's probably an attempt to work around [object-slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)?

Comment: @Aconcagua there's another snag, `dynamic_cast` only works on pointers and references.  I don't see either in this code.

Comment: almost. I can use smart pointers (that's not a problem), BUT anyway I want it to work like in Java, where I can do ```A a = new B()``` and it will work like B. Is it even possible in C++?

Comment: @MarkRansom Indeed – have been going to add/extend comments but others have been faster than me ;)

Comment: @Niles It *is* possible, but you *need* pointers or references for! Java does so as well, solely that it hides all this away from you... Remember that there are (implicit) reference types???

Comment: Yes. so ```std::share_ptr<A> a = std::make_ptr<B>("hello world");``` will return a pointer to "B"?

Comment: Side note: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)…

Comment: @Aconcagua I never use it. I wrote it here just to make things easier while asking ;)

Comment: You might do something like [that](https://godbolt.org/z/8vjqPzWhc).

Comment: Typically you'll do such things with `std::unique_ptr`s – these are much cheaper in construction (you don't want to pay for what you don't need) – unless you know for sure in advance that the object *will* be shared. Your function might look like `std::unique_ptr<A> s(int) { /*...*/ return std::make_unique<B>(""); /*...*/ }`.

Comment: The whole idea of inheritance is that a derived class models an "is a" concept. So usually when you need std::dynamic_cast it is a sign you need to either reconsider your design or check your code. It is much more common to access functionality through (abstract) baseclasses and overloaded virtual functions.

Comment: Can you explain to us what you are trying to do and why you think you need dynamic_cast?

Comment: By the way, even if you *do* fix all the issues around object slicing and so on you still won't get the desired output. You have defined global `operator<<`s for your types – but these are not considered if you have a pointer or reference to `A`! You need instead an operator accepting a `A` instance and call some *virtual* function on that one! Could look like: `class A { friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, A const& a) { a.printTo(s); return s; } virtual void printTo(ostream& s) = 0; };`

Comment: I think you would benefit from a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282). Trying to learn C++ by guessing is futile, and knowing some things about Java doesn't help.

Comment: @Niles *BUT anyway I want it to work like in Java* -- Do not use Java or any other programming language as a model in writing or learning C++.  All that will happen if you continure to go down that path are C++ programs that  1) Have bugs,  2) Inefficient, or 3) Will look weird to a C++ programmer.  Learn C++ as if Java doesn't exist.

Comment: No you don't want to work like java : Read this about [scopes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) and hopefully you will start to understand how different C++ is from Java

Comment: @PepijnKramer -- *So usually when you need std::dynamic_cast it is a sign you need to either reconsider your design* --  I think this is a case of what I mentioned in my last comment, and that is using Java techniques in a C++ program.  In Java, I have seen so much usage of `instanceof`, which is for all intent and purposes what `dynamic_cast` does.  The problem is that Java programmers are taught to use this first, instead of thinking about their design.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've seen the same with .Net. People use reflection if it is available..  Maybe Hyrum's law for languages ;)

Comment: Yes, it seems that programmers fall back to what's comfortable to them.  The problem is that what is comfortable in Java is not so in C++.